# Copy each td cell text to your clipboard with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to set a button to each td text in the table that will copy the contents to your clipboard.

I want to select the node contents of each text using jquery's this keyword. When I pass in the jQuery object it will throw an error.

It was working when I passed a unique ID, but when I passed a jQuery object it did not work. How can I achieve this efficiently?

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
   $('input[data-target]').on("click", function(){
      var docSelector = document.createRange();      
      var get_text = $(this);
      console.log(get_text);
      console.log(docSelector.selectNodeContents(get_text));
     
      var selection = window.getSelection();
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(docSelector);

      document.execCommand("copy");
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      
   });   
});
```

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <table>
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Copy</th>
       <th>Text</th>
     </tr>     
     <tr>
       <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy' value="X"></td>
       <td id='copy'> Copy some text </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy1' value="X"></td>
       <td id='copy1'> Copy some more text </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy2' value="X"></td>
       <td id='copy2'> Copy some even more text </td>
     </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
</html>
```

Comment: can you try it with      console.log(docSelector.selectNodeContents(get_text[0]));

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I did try that and get an undefined. Error message is no longer displayed but still non functional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the text of adjacent cell:

```
var get_text = $(this).closest('td').next()[0];
```

The snippet:

```js
$('input[data-target]').on("click", function(){
    var docSelector = document.createRange();
    var get_text = $(this).closest('td').next()[0];
    console.log(get_text);

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(docSelector);

    document.execCommand("copy");
    selection.removeAllRanges();

});
```

```css
table, th, td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Copy</th>
        <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy' value="X"></td>
        <td id='copy'> Copy some text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy1' value="X"></td>
        <td id='copy1'> Copy some more text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy2' value="X"></td>
        <td id='copy2'> Copy some even more text </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you I assumed this on it's own would take care of that. It's good insight for the future! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using `data-target` ID

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[data-target]').on("click", function() {
    var docSelector = document.createRange();
    var get_text = document.getElementById(this.dataset.target);
    docSelector.selectNodeContents(get_text)

    var selection = window.getSelection();
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(docSelector);

    document.execCommand("copy");
    selection.removeAllRanges();

  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Copy</th>
      <th>Text</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy' value="X"></td>
      <td id='copy'> Copy some text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy1' value="X"></td>
      <td id='copy1'> Copy some more text </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="button" data-target='copy2' value="X"></td>
      <td id='copy2'> Copy some even more text </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>

</html>
```